# Set background image programmatically to view: All Buttons are disappeared

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I set programmatically a background image to my view:

```
 UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wormhole.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView]
```

All buttons which i did put in storyboard on that view are disappeared, which is obviously no surprise, because there are now under the image, but how can i make the buttons visible again? I don't want to put an image view with my background image on the canvas and all the buttons on that image view.

Answer (score 3):

`addSubview:` will add the subview to the end of the subview collection, at the highest z-order.  The background will therefore cover everything else.

Replace the `addSubview:` with `insertSubview:atIndex:`, which will place it in back of all other subviews...

```
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

because all the buttons are on the back.

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

all you can bring all the buttons to the front.

Answer (score 1):

try this methods:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

or this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Wormhole.jpg"]];
```